# Label Studio: Importing Txt Files as Whole Files & Exporting the Result

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model, named-entity-recognition, conll, label-studio

I am trying to export the result of the file that I imported to Label Studio. This is my labeling interface :

```
<View>
  <Labels name="label" toName="text">
    <Label value="ILAC_ADI" background="red"/>
    <Label value="ETKIN_MADDE" background="darkorange"/>
    <Label value="ENDIKASYON" background="orange"/>
    <Label value="YAN_ETKI" background="green"/>
    <Label value="URETEN_SIRKET" background="green"/>
  <Label value="YARDIMCI_MADDE" background="#FFA39E"/><Label value="ORGAN" background="#D4380D"/></Labels>

  <Text name="text" value="$text" valueType="url" saveTextResult="yes" granularity="word"/>
</View>
```

and this is my text, although I am only getting the file path when I export it JSON-MIN.

2. Let's assume that I am successfully able to get the text data, then how can I use this for BERT model? I think we can only use IOB tagged data?

**Label Studio Annotation - Data Uploaded Successfully**
[image: Label Studio Annotation - Data Uploaded Successfully]
**Data Export Result**
[image]